# myTv+ app returns error code 100 when running on Android TV box

Tags: applications, android-tv

I have installed an app called myTv+ (https://mytv-plus.com/mytvws/) for Samsung A7 and it worked fine.

I tried to install it on the Android TV box (MX9 Pro 4K) but it's simply not working, just getting "Error Code: [100]".

I contacted the developer he said this app is designed only for the smartphone and "Error Code: [100]" means that your Android is rooted.

I noticed SuperSU on my Android TV box, I went for a full unrooting, yet the app still shows "Error Code: [100]".

Is there any way I can force the app to work with the Android TV box?

Comment: I don't have much experience with rooted Android-TVs but on Smartphones "rooted" often just means "your ROM is not genuine" according to Google SafetyNet check. Therefore unrooting does not help in such a case. The only way that could really bypass that check is to change the app, e.g. by decompiling and changing it (patching the checks away). Or alternatively you could try to hook the app using Frida and bypass the checks at run-time (both requires Android/Java programming knowledge).