# Run a supposedly incompatible app

Tags: applications

I copied an app from a TV Box to another TV Box of a different brand

The app is impossible to find online, and there is no replacement for it.

But when I open the app, I'm met with a message saying the "app is not compatible with this device". It's not a system-standard crash message, but one from within the app.

But it's clearly bull: This message takes some time to appear, and until that happens, the app appears to function normally (video streaming).

The donor TV Box is Android M, while the receiver is Android 10, fully rooted.

Using AppManager I tried revoking abilities like READ_PHONE_STATE, to see if I cripple the app's ability to identify the system. No success.

I'm willing to decompile the thing if I have to, but my knowledge doesn't go beyond that point...

---

**Edit:**

I think I thought of a different approach:

Is there a way to change the fingerprint of my device to emulate the intended host ? Serial number, and etc ? Can I fool the app into thinking it is running on the right platform ?

Comment: If the app can be installed and run, but then show such a message, then it's very likely that the check is done inside the app itself (the usual is checking root access as security prevention). If that's the case, then a root-hiding feature might help. Otherwise, you need to decompile and debug the app to know what is being checked specifically.

Comment: I'll try hiding the root. Not very hopeful, though, because since it's very unusual for a TV Box to be rooted, I don't believe they implemented such a check. Thank you.

Comment: Similar situation: [myTv+ app returns error code 100 when running on Android TV box](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236069/44325) which gave me an implication that some Android TV box is rooted/modified out-of-the-box.

Comment: Extended the question, if someone could help further  :)